# Using tertiary if-else

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use the tertiary if-else operator to assign values to a map key. I am getting the error "The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AddressLine1?'"

What am I doing wrong with the tertiary format?

I have more members of the map but I have only shown on key: value pair for simplicity.

```
class ItemsProperties {
  AddressLine1? formattedAddress;


  ItemsProperties({
    this.formattedAddress,
  });

  factory ItemsProperties.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      ItemsProperties(
 
        formattedAddress: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["formattedAddress"]) ?? '', AddressLine1.fromJson(json["formattedAddress"]), <<< ERROR ON THIS LINE
      );
}
```

Comment: There is no ternary if-else operator used in your code.  You are using the "if-null" operator, but you probably intend to do `AddressLine1.fromJson(json["formattedAddress"] ?? '')` and not `AddressLine1.fromJson(json["formattedAddress"]) ?? ''`.  Note the placement of the parentheses; your code is checking if `AddressLine1.fromJson()` returns `null`, and if so, fall back to an empty string.